# Better explanation why this was closed by Phillip

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14472/are-bill-clinton-and-barack-obama-the-only-two-us-presidents-to-pardon-or-commut) was summarily closed.

It is objective question.  It explores an important policy departure from mainstream consensus, the pardoning or commuting of unrepentant terrorists.

That the motives and sympathies of the Obama and Clinton regimes can be seen as questionable in light of the question is not the fault of the question.  It is the fault of those pursuing the policy in the first place.  And I think this is the only reason that the question was closed.  Please consider re-opening.

Answer (score 7):

A question is:

> What do you think of the colour red?

A leading question is:

> What do you think of the ugly colour red?

If we're being generous then the question you asked is an 3-paragraph highly suggestive leading question.

Some more examples:

Question:

> Why does Trump dislike Mexicans?

Leading question:

> Trump is a racist and spreads lies about Mexicans. Which other Presidents had such a hate-on for Mexicans?

Question:

> Did Obama's economic policies help or harm the U.S. economy?

Leading question:

> Obama's economic policy was an unmitigated disaster. How much money did we lose?

Well, and so forth...

---

> It is objective question

To paraphrase Arthur Dent: "*This must be some strange and obscure usage of the word 'objective' I was not previously aware of*".

It's really not an objective question. It's full of highly controversial assumptions and interpretation of events. Weaselwords like "leftists" aren't improving things either, and accusing the modern Democratic party for the U.S. history of slavery really takes the cake.

In short, the text of your question is full of information that is controversial. Many will disagree with it. You could be completely right for all I care, that's not the point. The point is that this is a site which attempts to build content based on *expertise*, and not *opinion*. Opinionated questions are simply not a good fit. It's just not what we do. I strongly urge you to read [this](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25/11249) and [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) if you haven't already to better understand what we do and what we *don't* do.

---

There is certainly a salvageable question here. Look at [Why did Obama commute Chelsea Manning's sentence?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/14458/11249) for an example (but other questions could be asked as well).
However, judging by the (now-deleted) comments you've left on my answer there, it seems you didn't exactly grasp the difference between "please explain this person's motivation" and "please offer your opinion on this" there.

Comment: The FALN terrorists are Marxist terrorists.  How else to describe them?  Certainly not as mainstream, blue-collar Democrats.

Comment: @KDog The text of your question is full of information that is controversial. Many will disagree with it. You could be completely right for all I care – that's not the point. The point is that this is a site which attempts to build content based on *expertise*, and not *opinion*. Opinionated questions are simply not a good fit. *It's not what we do*. I strongly urge you to read [this](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/a/25) and [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) if you haven't already to better understand what we do and what we *don't* do.

Comment: there is nothing in the question that is in factual dispute. Both Obama and Clinton both pardoned unrepentant terrorists. The only thing that is seemingly controversial is discussing that they did so.

Comment: Thank you, @Carpetsmoker. I couldn't explain it much better.

Answer (score 6):

I can't speak for Phillip, but If I came across your "question" I would have closed it because it looks like it's intended to make a point and not seek information.  In essence, It's a rant in disguise.

see the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for more details

> **To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …**
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”